# How to replace NULL with "No Data" in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to figure out how to replace NULL values with a string that just says "No Data" or "Missing Data". Instead of showing a NULL value on the client-side which has no meaning for the user, how can I return NULL values in my MongoDB collection as "No Data" or "Missing Data"?

I guess the easiest (and maybe a longer) way would be to modify the original data.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in the database itself? It may seem easier, but you might just make it harder for yourself: let's say the string is someone's name. What do you do if someone is actually called "No Data"? Or, more likely, what do you do if someone is German and would prefer to see something like "(n.v.)" instead of "No Data"?

Comment: I'm not sure you want to do that in the database. Null value use way less disk space than a string. I recommend you change the returned value within your application. If someone query the database itself, there is chances that it's a dev or a dba, and then, Null will mean something.

Comment: @ConstantinGuay So do you mean replace Null value with something else on the client-side?

Comment: @WanderNauta Fair point. In my case I am showing addresses so was just trying to find a better way to show a missing address rather than Null.

Comment: Pseudocode: `if doc.fieldname == null { print("No data. Doh!") }` Almost every template language can achieve that. Separation of concerns. It should be decided in the frontend how a `null`value has to be presented. Otherwise you'd have to change code when all somebody wants is to leave out the "Doh!".

Comment: @mapr yes, exactly. As Markus said, you have to split the content of the database, and what is displayed to user. Per example, in case of translation, you don't want to keep all translation of all fields in your database.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Ok, makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you use aggregation, you can use $ifNull.